# Change component works in Normal React but not in SPFx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, spfx

I have a root component that has:

```
  function aceRender(stepNum: number) {
    switch (stepNum) {
      case 1:
        return (<div><RequestStep1Body /></div>); break;
      case 2:
        return (<div><RequestStep2Body /></div>); break;
      case 3:
        return (<div><RequestStep3Body /></div>); break;
    default:       break;
  }
}
  return (
    <div ><p> Current Step {step}</p>
      <div><RequestHeader /></div>
      {aceRender(step)}
    </div>
  );
```

'step' is a state that when changed from the inside the 'RequestHeader' component , draws the appropriate child component  'RequestStep{n}Body'
But if the state is changed from inside either RequestStep1Body, RequestStep2Body or RequestStep3Body component, the `return (<div><RequestStep1Body /></div>);`  causes the webpart to disappear with error:

```
TypeError: n is not a function
    at sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at Bi (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at is (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at cs (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at uc (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at Bi (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at lc (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
    at Xs (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_eec15c86d62ce90f8fe18e58491cf728.js:70)
```

the same code used in a React only app works fine. so I assume the issue is with SPFx.

Any one can show an SPFx example that allows for changing the appetence of component in the web part from inside a visible component?
Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same version of React and other libraries in your "normal" react app and in the SPFx app?

Comment: SPFx is using a fixed set of other libraries (like react), of specific version. Your code needs to be compatible with those. From what it looks, the application you copied the code from is using a different version of either react or other related libraries. Therefore the code does not seem to run as-is. This probably has nothing to do with SPFx.

Comment: Both of you are right. when I downgraded the react app to 16.13.1 like the SPFx app, the same error showed up. I tried upgrading the SPFx to 17.0.2 , the web part shows error:"Manifest not found for component id "0d910c1c-13b9-4e1c-9aa4-b008c5e42d7d" and version "17.0.2"."                                    Is there no way to use React 17? or another way to change the parent component from a child?

Comment: React 17 is not supported by SPFx. Maybe it will in be the future, though. Modifying parent component from a child should not be an issue, and is done usually (not only in SPFx, but in general) by sending events to the parent from the child, informing the parent that it should modify itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, then I found this post:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8660

All I did was to run this command and it worked:

```
npm i react@17.0.1 react-dom@17.0.1 @types/react@17.0.45 @types/react-dom@17.0.17 --save-exact
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: It was long upgraded and went through new issues :-)  Thank you